# Android: read email using ContentProvider

Tags: android, email, android-contentprovider

I want to read email from an Android device (Wildfire S), from the default HTC mail application, something similar to reading SMS, using the ContentProvider:

```
Uri allMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(allMessage, null, null, null, null);
while  (c.moveToNext()) {
    smss.add(new SMSObject(c)); //custom object which just retrieves all fields
}
```

Something similar should be available for mail as well, so i check all available ContentProviders:

```
for (PackageInfo pack : getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS)) {
    ProviderInfo[] providers = pack.providers;
    if (providers != null) {
        for (ProviderInfo provider : providers) {
            Log.d("Example", "provider: " + provider.authority);
        }
    }
}
```

In this list (which contained thing like `gmail-ls`, `sms` and `com.android.calendar`, so I'm on the right track) I found `mail`, so I tried this:

```
Uri allMessage = Uri.parse("content://mail/");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(allMessage, null, null, null, null);
while  (c.moveToNext()) {
    emails.add(new SMSObject(c)); //custom object. should work with emails as well
}
```

But I got this exception:

`11-14 11:48:42.105: E/AndroidRuntime(3609): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.me.emailretriever/nl.me.emailretriever.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.htc.android.mail.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{40685dd8 3609:nl.me.emailretriever/10076} (pid=3609, uid=10076) requires com.htc.android.mail.permission.READ_MAIL or com.htc.android.mail.permission.WRITE_MAIL`...
`11-14 11:48:42.105: E/AndroidRuntime(3609): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.htc.android.mail.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{40685dd8 3609:nl.me.emailretriever/10076} (pid=3609, uid=10076) requires com.htc.android.mail.permission.READ_MAIL or com.htc.android.mail.permission.WRITE_MAIL`

So I added both permissions, but to no avail.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.android.mail.permission.WRITE_MAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.android.mail.permission.READ_MAIL" />
```

How can I read/access emails like I can access SMSs? Why do I get an exception, although I have the required permissions?

Comment: did you get to do this somehow ?

Comment: @sayed.jalil No, unfortunately, I was not able to.